# What is the cheapest way to iterate through all cosmos documents?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos resource with a 'products' collection. There are *many* documents in this collection. Enough such that I will often see a lot of 429s during busy periods despite a fair amount of provisioned throughput.

What is the cheapest way (with regards to R/Us) to iterate through every single product?

Assumptions:

- Assume I must, ultimately, touch every single document - but assume I can do this in batches - it doesn't need to be one single operation. e.g. if skip/take was the right approach - that could work despite some docs being processed before others

Comment: Which API are you using in Cosmos?

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified - NoSQL SDK in .Net

Answer (score 2):

Using Change Feed should be the cheapest. You can do it with a myriad of options (Spark Connector, Azure Functions, etc), but if you are already working on .NET, the most straight forward would be with the [Change Feed Pull model](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-pull-model?tabs=dotnet)

```
FeedIterator<YourType> iteratorForTheEntireContainer = container.GetChangeFeedIterator<YourType>(ChangeFeedStartFrom.Beginning(), ChangeFeedMode.LatestVersion);

while (iteratorForTheEntireContainer.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<YourType> response = await iteratorForTheEntireContainer.ReadNextAsync();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Completed full read of entire container");
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach (YourType item in response)
        {
            // process item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks VERY much. I'd never even heard of this. Can I ask - what makes this 'cheaper' than a skip/take if the result of hitting every single document is the same anyway? Thanks again

Comment: Change Feed cannot apply any filters nor projections. It's a different operation than Query. Query has more options but is more expensive RU wise.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the cheapest way (with regards to R/Us) to iterate through
> every single product?

You can't get any cheaper than zero RU so definitely worth mentioning [the analytical store here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction).

If you have many documents and need to process all of them this definitely sounds like something very suited to that.

Until recently if you were using the continuous backup model then analytical store was not possible but [it is now possible](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-azure-synapse-link-compatibility-with-cosmos-db-continuous-backup/) to enable the synapse link feature on such accounts.

In terms of actual monetary "cost" then the analytical store itself is not free. But I have found in accounts with it enabled the cost is extremely minor compared to the transactional store cost. Certainly if it allows you to lower provisioned RU by getting this kind of expensive operation out of the transactional store this can more than break even.